# Add element w/ text node after user selection

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that creates a new text node at the end of a document when called, using the value of text within a text field:

```
   function addAfter () {
      var elem = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
      var h = document.createElement('span');
      var t = document.createTextNode(elem);    
      h.appendChild(t);
      document.body.appendChild(h);
   }
```

What I would like it to do would be to add the text immediately after user-selected text (like when you click and drag to select text). What needs to replace the `document.body.appendChild(h);` for this to work?

Comment: And what does *"user-selected text"* mean ?

Comment: As in, when you click and drag over text and it gets highlighted

Comment: There's no event for that

Answer (score 1):

[Try This JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k82zvppg/)

This should do it on anything but IE edge(I believe)

```
    function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
(window.getSelection()) ? addText(window.getSelection().toString(), window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode) : addText(document.selection.toString(), document.selection.baseNode.parentNode);
});

function addText(text, parent) {
parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

The way that this works is it uses the mouseUp event to determine whether or not text MAY have been selected. Selected text is stored underneath window.getSelected() OR document.selected() - it then passes that value as well as the parent of the selected text to the addText function. It uses the document appendChild and createTextNode methods to append the captured text to the DOM.

In Previous Versions of IE they used document.select(), but in Edge they switched over to getSelection(like everyone else) BUT they didn't implement the same value that's returned when you get text, ergo you can't really grab the parentNode and easily append to that node.

So, in short, this will give you what you're looking for, but it's not cross-browser and there doesn't appear to be a way to do that easily.

Answer (score 1):

I manipulated a solution that I found on another feed.

```
  function addAfter (isBefore) {
var sel, range, node;
var changeText = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
var textAndCode = "<span class=\"correction\"> " + changeText + " </span>";
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.collapse(isBefore);

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but was
        // until recently non-standard and not supported in all browsers
        // (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = textAndCode;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.collapse(isBefore);
    range.pasteHTML(textAndCode);
}
}
```

You just have to pass in the value for `isBefore` as false if you want it to appear after.